# Disconnected graph with degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a disconnected graph with degree sequence $(4$, $4$, $3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)$?

Comment: By "disconnected", do you mean to indicate that the graph certainly has at least two components, or do you instead mean "possibly disconnected"?

Answer (score 2):

One component must have at least 5 vertices. Any other must have at least 4.  But you only have 8 vertices.